# Peugeot 206 LX (2002), I have installed a cd player which works but it doesn't remember volume/clock settings

Tags: audio, wiring, peugeot

I have installed  a new CD player [Philips CEM2100](http://www.p4c.philips.com/cgi-bin/dcbint/cpindex.pl?slg=en&scy=cl&ctn=CEM2100/00) it works but when I turn the car on and off it loses several settings such as:

Volume, eu region for radio (this may be because I haven't fitted the arial) and last playing cd track data.

I have heard that you can swap a few wires around to fix this issue, but dont know which ones.

Here is an image of the wires in my car.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/JPpOm.jpg]

Here is an image of the back of the CD player.

[image: http://imgur.com/JPpOm,GzKmB#1]

Comment: Before you start swapping wires in your wiring harness, have you tried checking to make sure the battery cables on your car are tight? The most common reason for radios resetting is a cable being loose and losing connection when the car is turned off.

Comment: @sly No I havent this is the first time I've done anything to a car other than drive it. Normally I build and programme computers. How would I check the cables are tight? Are the battery cables the ones I have photographed or are they in the bonnet?

Comment: The battery cables that are connected to the battery. They would be under the hood. If one of the cables are loose, you should be able to move it with your hand.

Comment: OK I'll try that, if its not that do you have any other ideas what it could be or what I could check?

Comment: Trying to think of other things it could be. That's all I can think of right now. The radio is somehow losing power if it's resetting.

Comment: If it helps it only looses settings when the car is turned off. It doesn't reset or anything like that during use.

Comment: Yeah. It's losing power somewhere, more than likely the battery cables.

Comment: Did you get an adapter plug or did you cut the OEM wires?

Answer (score 4):

The yellow wire needs to be connected to +12 volts all the time (even with the car off), it sounds like you have this wire connected to switch power. This is the memory wire for the radio that allows it to retain settings when the car is off.

I may be wrong on the color of the wire, I was basing my information on the manual provided by [Phillips here (PDF download)](http://download.p4c.philips.com/files/c/cem2100_00/cem2100_00_dfu_aen.pdf) But the wire colors listed in the manual don't match what's in your picture. Below is a screenshot of page 9 of the manual.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The colours Larry listed are the ISO standard ones, which it seems Peugeot don't follow.

The permanent live should be pin 7, which is the thick blue wire in your photo. The thin blue wire in pin 4 should be live when the ignition is on. Pin 8 (yellow & green) should be ground, and pin 5 (white) should power the electic aerial. The others are ignored in your stereo (as it only has 4 connections in the socket), and are probably used by Peugeot for steering wheel controls.

Comment: So the connectors in the pictures are the factory connectors?

Comment: I believe so - I think all new cars in Europe have had to have ISO connectors for the past decade or so.

Comment: Nice we have a standard but the OEM doesn't follow them. Okay that makes more sense, I thought what was pictured was the pigtail that came with the radio.

Comment: That's what standards are for isn't it ;) At least they've fitted the right plug...

Comment: But that's almost worse, the plug fit's but the wires are in the wrong place.

Comment: I think they're in the right place, just the wrong colours. Green&Yellow, for example, is the European standard for earth cables for mains wiring, so I suspect that is their logic for using it for ground cables in a car (despite everyone else using black or brown...) No idea why they're using sky blue for power though!